# using the evaluate feature in nltk tagged documents

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram, pos-tagger

I am new to nltk and python.  I was trying to use the evaluate feature to test the accuracy of the text document that I read.  This is what I have so far.

```
    from nltk.tag import UnigramTagger
    from nltk.corpus import treebank
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
    train_sents = treebank.tagged_sents() 
    tagger = UnigramTagger(train_sents) 
    text1 = "This is the first sentence.  Now this is another one!   
              How many do you plan to write?" 
    words = word_tokenize(text1) 
    value = tagger.tag(words) 
    accuracy = tagger.evaluate(words)
```

I am unable to compute the accuracy, using this.  I get the following error.

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack.

I am not sure how to correct this. Thanks.

Comment: Tagger evaluation input is a list of tuples =)

Answer (score 0):

To train and use a `UnigramTagger` using NLTK:

```
>>> from nltk.tag import UnigramTagger
>>> from nltk.corpus import treebank
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> sent1 = "This is the first sentence."
>>> train_sents = treebank.tagged_sents()
>>> tagger = UnigramTagger(train_sents)
>>> tagger.tag(word_tokenize(sent1))
[('This', u'DT'), ('is', u'VBZ'), ('the', u'DT'), ('first', u'JJ'), ('sentence', u'NN'), ('.', u'.')]
```

To evaluate the tagger, you would need to have annotated sentences to validate the tags from the tagger. The input to the `UnigramTagger.evaluate()` is a list of tuples, where the first item in the tuple is the word and the second item in the tuple is the POS (i.e. the same input type as the `UnigramTagger.train()` function).
.

See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/api.py#L53 
So let's first split the treebank sentences into 2 parts, 90% and 10%:

```
>>> train_sents = treebank.tagged_sents()
>>> treebank_sents = treebank.tagged_sents()
>>> len(treebank_sents)
3914
>>> int(0.9 * len(treebank_sents))
3522
>>> train_sents = treebank.tagged_sents()[:3522]
>>> test_sents = treebank.tagged_sents()[3522:]
>>> tagger = UnigramTagger(train_sents)
>>> tagger.evaluate(test_sents)
0.8647328244274809
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I see that the 'evaluate' command works for data already in the corpus.  I was wondering if there was a way to get it to work for my sentence, that is for data not existing in the corpus.

Comment: you have to manually annotate your corpus to use `evaluate()`